# OrientDB - How to configure OSystem database path?

Tags: orientdb

Since 2.2.0, OrientDB now has a system database named OSystem.  I'm looking for a way to configure the path to this database independently from other databases?  Is this possible?  Can I do this at runtime with environment variables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported.

However, I'll try to add support for this in an upcoming release.

Thanks for the suggestion.

-Colin

OrientDB LTD
The Company behind OrientDB

Answer (score 0):

I've done some tests, trying to set different paths in `orientdb-server-config.xml` properties, but after every server start OrientDB checks for `OSystem` DB presence, and if there is no one, it will automatically create it in default `/databases/` folder:

`2016-06-17 15:13:26:738 INFO  {db=OSystem} Creating the system database 'OSystem' for current server [OSystemDatabase]`